# How to post to Facebook timeline using format like pinterest?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

When you share a photo from a Facebook album it gets diplayed "full width" layout in the timeline (about 567px wide) with a caption below.

I also noticed that shared images from pinterest get shown im a format with an image and caption underneath.

But when I share a photo from elsewhere using the "picture" property of the feed dialog, or a page containing an og:image tag, it always gets displayed in thumbnail (116x116)|text layout.

The images from pinterest are posted as actions, so that may be a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feed dialog will not get you this customization you will need to use Open Graph actions.

https://developers.facebook.com/showcase/pinterest/

[image: Pinterest image layout]

Also for full width photos from applications, the user must have generated the photo from the app so that you can utilize "User Generated Photos"

For example the following is from the Tumblr application

[image: Tumblr user generated photo]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/adding-photos-to-stories/

Comment: Thanks for useful answer. I suspected it was a OG actions thing. What I don't know is whether I get to style the post, beyond what can be done with feed dialog. (I can't use "user_generated" photos because they aren't!).